# Is $S_i(1,2,\dots,p-2) \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for all values of $i$ whenever $p$ is prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial, congruences, symmetric-polynomials

Let $S_i(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ denote the $i$th elementary symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables. Is $S_i(1,2,\dots,p-2) \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for all values of $i$ from $0$ to $(p-2)$ whenever $p$ is prime?

Since $$\sum_{0}^{p-2} S_i(1,2,\dots,p-2) = (p-1)!,$$ it's obvious that  $$\sum_{0}^{p-2}S_i(1,2,\dots,p-2)\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$ I don't know, however, if this sum can ever be different from $(p-1)$.

Answer (score 8):

(There's no need for the superscripts on elementary symmetric polynomials $e_i$.)

As Vieta's formula states, $e_i(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ will be the $i$th coefficient of $(T+x_1)\cdots(T+x_n)$.

According to Euler's theorem, $x^{p-1}\equiv 1$ mod $p$ for all $x$, so the polynomial $T^{p-1}-1$ has every integer residue $1,\cdots,p-1$ as a zero. Since the integers mod $p$ form a field, zeros correspond to linear factors in any polynomial's factorization, hence $T^{p-1}-1\equiv (T-1)\cdots(T-(p-1))$.

Therefore mod $p$:

$$\begin{array}{ll} (T+1)\cdots(T+(p-2)) & \equiv(T-(p-1))\cdots(T-2) \\ & \equiv(T^{p-1}-1)/(T-1) \\ & \equiv T^{p-2}+\cdots+T^2+T+1.\end{array}$$

Evidently all the coefficients are $1$ mod $p$.

Comment: @LucasDaSilvaPereira A variable that makes up a polynomial. For example mod $5$, $$(T-1)(T-2)(T-3)(T-4)\equiv T^4-1.$$

Comment: @Lucas Um, how do you know $T^{p-1}-1$ factors as $(T-1)\cdots(T-(p-1))$ if you don't know about the things you're asking and think $\pm1$ are the only zeros? Anyway, $x^{p-1}-1\equiv 0$ mod $p$ for a given value of $x$ is precisely what it *means* for $x$ to be a "zero of the polynomial $T^{p-1}-1$." Since every $x\equiv 1,\cdots,p-1$ satisfies $x^{p-1}\equiv1$, every such residue is a zero of the polynomial, and hence the factorization. No, of course $\pm1$ are not the only roots mod $p$ (they are the only roots in the real number system as $p-1$ is even is probably what you're thinking).

Comment: As for what happens when $p$ is composite, go ahead and expand out $(T+1)\cdots(T+p-2)$ mod $p$ for $p=4$ and $p=6$ to see for yourself.